# Posting JSON to database with Curl

Tags: json, curl

So I'm attempting to add some information to a database of cameras. The way to do this (according to those who made this database) is to use Curl with the command:

```
    curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "$DATA"
 <cam2api_domain>/cameras/
```

Where "cam2api_domain" is the url of the database and "$DATA" is the camera info. After observing what one of the database entries looks like:

`[{"description":"Camera in Kenya recording lions","resolution_h":1080,"resolution_w":1920,"inactive":null,"traffic":null,"last_updated":"2017-10-31T01:48:28.427749Z","city":"Nairobi","state":"None","pk":1,"lng":36.8163,"lat":-1.2804,"retrieval_model":{"ip":"10.0.0.1","port":80},"source":"google","camera_type":"IP","camera_id":26065,"outdoors":null,"is_video":null,"date_added":"2017-10-31T01:48:28.427709Z","source_url":"www.google.com","country":"Kenya"}]`

I began attempting to create a new entry using the following command:

[My trial command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPKxt.png)

As you can see I keep getting the error 
`{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 15 (char 14)"}`

I can't determine the cause of this error as I was told that a new camera entry doesn't need to have all of it fields specified (just the ones I used are necessary).  I also tried adding a camera with every field filled in but received the same results.  Does anyone know why this is the case?